# Bootstrap 4 responsive navbar that collapses at xs width?

Tags: navbar, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to find an example of the bootstrap 4 responsive navbar that collapses to a hamburger button only at the xs width but is fully visible when wider.

There's a bootstrap 3 [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) that Just Works, but nothing for 4 that I've found.

The bootstrap 4 navbar examples page shows a [collapsed content](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsible-content) version but it's collapsed at all widths.

And below it hints at how to make it work using .navbar-toggler, et. al.

> For more complex navbar patterns, like those used in Bootstrap v3, use the .navbar-toggleable-* classes in conjunction with the .navbar-toggler. These classes override our responsive utilities to show navigation only when content is meant to be shown.

I have minimal bootstrap knowledge so any solution I don't want to fight the framework if there's already a sanctioned way to do this.

**Edit:**

Actually, the Responsive Navbar example below the [Collapsible content](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsible-content) in bootstrap 4 documentation does exactly what I was looking for using the *navbar-toggleable-xs* class. I didn't see it earlier because I didn't make the window narrow enough.

Comment: You have already answered your question. Use `.navbar-toggleable-xs`

Comment: @ManojKumar So many classes to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @ourmandave please add your edit as an answer and accept it, so this question can be closed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Bootstrap 4 stable:

In the stable version `navbar-toggleable-*` has been renamed to `navbar-expand-*`, but the `-xs` infix is (*still*) removed, so in your case you should use **`navbar-expand`**.

Explanation in the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#how-it-works

#### Only for Bootstrap 4 alpha:

Actually, the Responsive Navbar example below the [Collapsible content](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsible-content) in Bootstrap 4 documentation does exactly what I was looking for using the `navbar-toggleable-xs` class. I didn't see it earlier because I didn't make the window narrow enough.

In Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, it’s now simply `navbar-toggleable` without the `-xs`.

**EDIT**: The documentation link is now here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav

Comment: because -xs does not exist anymore at all in the grid system!