# Collapsible navbar items disappear when using toggler in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4 for the first time, and I am trying to do something that was quite easy in Bs3: I want link items in my navbar to collapse to a hamburger menu when screen size is `xs`.

Now the [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsible-content) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321110/bootstrap-4-responsive-navbar-that-collapses-at-xs-width) sort of touch on this, but I appear to be following the correct classes, and yet when the screen is sized XS, the link items do not collapse - they just disappear.

Here's the [JSFiddle with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/ang852ev/) for the full view, but here's what I am doing with my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light" style="background-color: #E4491C; padding: 0px;">
  <p id="toptext">Test</p>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light" style="background-color: #002b52">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TopDog</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="pull-sm-right navbar-brand2" href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="pull-sm-right navbar-brand2" href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

So I am using `toggleable` class, I am specifying these as link-items; the only difference I can spot is that I am also using a `pull-sm-right` class, which should bring the links to the right side of the nav. Removing them did not fix the issue.

**Question:** Why is Bootstrap failing to display these links as a collapsible menu when I resize the page?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's responsive menu. The links hides when it reaches 768 pixels and the navbar-header is only visible as well as Hamburger Menu Icon.

It looks like the Hamburger Menu Icon is missing too, that's because you didn't add it.

Use this code to add it:

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
&#9776;
```

Good luck.